# DotNet :- How to send and get data between windows form app and web site?

Tags: .net

I want to develop an app which can send and receive data from a website. to be precise i want to make a windows form app of a website now.

Comment: What have you looked at? There are a myriad of options; any of them will work...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you have control over the web site?

- Yes: Create some kind of Web Service API with which applications can integrate.  Be it SOAP or WCF or anything, the idea is to provide the functionality without all that messy UI that applications don't need.  Then your application would just access the web service API.
- No: You can perhaps take a "screen scraping" approach, though it's a good deal messier.  You'd create HttpWebRequest objects which set GET/POST requests to the page(s) in question and read the response.  This can get particularly ugly if the page has a lot of dynamic content because you're just going to get the page source, not the browser-rendered output.  Other requests may need to be sent for additional content.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I am new to .net , please help me what topics i should explore to get better knowledge on this

Comment: @James: That's a pretty broad request, actually.  The topics you will need to learn and explore will present themselves over time as you encounter problems that you need to solve.  There isn't much of a direct approach.  If you're more interested in code, you go one route.  If you're more interested in tools and products, you go another route.  Etc.

Answer (score 0):

You can form a [WebRequest](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webrequest(v=vs.71).aspx) in your windows form app and then use some form of web service/WCF endpoint to then send data back and forth; [an example is on this page](http://bytes.com/topic/net/answers/124382-generating-web-request-winform-application-using-webservi).